# Как сделать горизонтальный скрол для таблицы?

Tags: html, css

Структура

```
<div>
                  <table className='directory__table' key={ subCategory.id }>
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>ФИО</th>
                        <th>Должность</th>
                        <th>Внешний телефон</th>
                        <th>Внутренний телефон</th>
                        <th>Описание</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      {
                        subCategory.data.map(data =>
                          <tr key={ data.id }>
                            <td>{ data.name }</td>
                            <td>{ data.rank }</td>
                            <td>{ data.phone }</td>
                            <td>{ data.mainPhone }</td>
                            <td>{ data.description }</td>
                          </tr>
                        )
                      }
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
```

пытаюсь задать родительскому диву overflow-x scroll, таблице задаю фикс ширину например 500, но таблица все равно растягивает родительские элементы. Если я задам диву фикс ширину - все заработает, но мне надо что бы родительский див всегда был по размеру страницы. Как сделать горизонтальный скрол в этом случае?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Контейнеру можно сделать ширину 100% и оверфлов : авто
тогда когда таблица не будет помещаться, будет появляться скролл

```css
.table-wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="table-wrapper">
                  <table className='directory__table' key={ subCategory.id }>
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>ФИО</th>
                        <th>Должность</th>
                        <th>Внешний телефон</th>
                        <th>Внутренний телефон</th>
                        <th>Описание</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                      {
                        subCategory.data.map(data =>
                          <tr key={ data.id }>
                            <td>{ data.name }</td>
                            <td>{ data.rank }</td>
                            <td>{ data.phone }</td>
                            <td>{ data.mainPhone }</td>
                            <td>{ data.description }</td>
                          </tr>
                        )
                      }
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </div>
```

Comment: сделал width: 100%; overflow-x: auto; и для таблице 500px и на низких разрешениях все равно блоки родители растягиваются

Comment: если я правильно понял, то вот, смотри, тут рабочий вариант https://codepen.io/frankyjo/pen/OJEPKrR